# Chaining a sequence of javascript events with intermediate delays

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delay

I'm trying to run events sequentially, with delays between some events.

For example, I `click` on a button, my first event starts with this `click`, the duration is 3000ms, and I put a delay of 3100, and then a second event start.

I want to start a third event when the second event is over, and then a fourth when the third is over.

It isn't that difficult with `setTimeOut`, but it's not working well on smartphones, as it requires too much of our connection.

What I would like is something like this:

```
delay(3100, function(){
blabla
});.delay().delay().
```

etc. etc.

I'm sure I'm not clear because of my bad English - thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be best off with [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout). It works pretty much as your example above, though you can't chain them together, you can nest them to your liking by calling setTimeout() inside setTimeout() and so on... If the function you need to execute is always the same, you may use a named function instead of a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$("button").click(function() {
      $("first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
      $("div.second").slideUp(300).fadeIn(400);
    });
```

Also view this link http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: You should note that this examples is from the official [API](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: I know that I have only tell explanation of delay function